Occupation state rule for anyons and their existence in 2D and lower
Can somebody please explain the occupation state rule for anyons? For fermions, they follow the pauli exclusion principle, while multiple bosons can occupy the same state. I understand that anyons have properties that are intermediate to those of fermions and bosons, but I cannot understand how this intermediary affects the occupation state rules for anyons.
Also, why are there only two types of particles (bosons and fermions) in 3D and higher? Why can they not be found in 2D and lower? and why are anyons are found in 2D and lower dimensions?
Any simpler explanations would be greatly appreciated. I have not studied topology at all. However, statements like "Only fermions and bosons are found in 3D and higher dimensions while anyons are found in 2D and lower dimensions" are very common in most condensed matter physics papers. These papers do not delve into more details and these statements are taken as facts.
Thanks

Have you read the pioneering article from 77 by Leinaas & Myrheim? They give a good account of the role of spatial dimensionality in that paper. Also, fermions and bosons can certainly exist in both 1, 2, and 3 dimensions. But anyons are confined to less than 3.

Related: link

How can bosons and fermions exist in <3 dimensions? In the link that you shared, from what I understand is that if we take rotation groups into consideration, then they exist <3 dimensions. How are permutation groups different from rotation groups? Are they not the same? As in when you take one particle around another then you can have rotation group which is same as permutation. Is this not right?

In 1 and 2 dimensions you can get "any" phase factor $\exp(i \phi)$ when permuting two particles, depending on what type of particle they are and what system you are considering. If your particles give you $\phi = 2 \pi k$ then we call them bosons, if they give you $\phi = \pi + 2 \pi k$ we call them fermions. There is nothing excluding these "special" angles in 1D or 2D.

Okay got it. Thanks, but I do not get why it was mentioned that these particles exist in >=3 dimensions in the first two chapters of this book by Albert Lerda (link) and also why my lecturer said the same.

Also another question on the occupation rule for anyons. For bosons, multiple bosons can occupy the same site. For fermions, they fill in based on Pauli exclusion principle. What would be the case for anyons? It's mentioned in the A Lerda's book that anyons show intermediate behaviors between bosons and fermions.

Yeah, I don't know the answer to that question, otherwise I would have answered your post :)
